# Losing coolant head gasket been done

Tags: ford, coolant-leak, fusion

I have been loosing coolant since November I have spent so much money on my car fordfusion auto
Its had the head gasket done , water pump , thermostat, new radiator, new coolant and cap
But I still have the problem no one seems to know why this is still happening

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you're just throwing parts at this problem and hoping you find it.  I didn't see where you did any actual diagnostic tests to determine WHERE the lost coolant was going.  This is important:

1. Out the exhaust - usually a head gasket, warped or cracked head or block.  An exhaust gas analyzer will tell you if there is coolant in the exhaust.  Then you take off the head(s) and start inspecting.  Usually there is visual evidence of the coolant making its way to the cylinder but not always.  Check for warped head, warped block.  Cracks are harder to find but any reputable shop will be able to perform the needed tests.
2. Into the oil - usually caused by the same things as above.  Often there will be foam and residue in the oil but not always.  An oil analysis will tell you if there is coolant in the oil.
3. Into the world - Radiator, hose, water pump, fitting leaks, bad cooling system cap, etc. can cause this.  Usually you will find residue at the point of the leak but sometimes you need some UV dye to help pinpoint the problem.  Again a reputable shop will have the skills and tools to do this.

There is really nowhere else for the coolant to go.  So once you find where it's going then you can work to fix it.